# Keep the gnome terminal open after the program is finished

Tags: terminal, gnome

This script opens a gnome terminal and 4 tabs in it , but once the program finishes the tabs gets closed so i can't see the output. It doesn't happen when i run each program manually. How can keep the tab open , even when the program is finished .

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "optirun yarpserver" \
           --tab -e "sh -c 'sleep 20 ; optirun iCub_SIM'" \
           --tab -e "sh -c 'sleep 86 ; optirun simCartesianControl'" \
           --tab -e "sh -c 'sleep 116 ; optirun iKinCartesianSolver --context simCartesianControl/conf --part left_arm'" \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to do it on the command line (`man gnome-terminal` doesn't seem to indicate a specific option for that, but you can start a `gnome-terminal`, set specific options (one of which would be "When command exits: Hold the terminal open"), and save your settings as a specific profile. There is a command-line option for selecting a specific profile to use, so that should accomplish what you want.